# 404 page is not showing

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I don't know why my site is not showing 404 page instead giving this output

Warning: include(none): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /thefundu/public_html/friedcoffee/wp-includes/template-loader.php on line 75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the warning comes from PHP's settings to show warnings. ( its the default instalation setting)

you dont get a (apache) 404 becouse with wp the page you requested was index.php. So for apache you got your page (index.php). and its not a 404, its the index.php.

normaly u get a 404 from wp. but in this case u got a error and the wp own 404 was not handled.

your wp is not working right and fails to load the file. The end result is a empty page becouse it could not load anything else. ( the warning is a diferent way of output not part of your page )

i am no wp expert but include(none) says to me that you have no templated selected... maybe u need a template.

( the wp 404 error uses the template to make the wp 404 look shiny :D... the apache 404 just says "Not found" in ugly letters. ( and then there are browsers that also handle 404 to make it look beter ) )

---

edit :

considering u want to figure this out. Open the Template-loader.php and add echo's around what u want to know.

echo the $template before the include. its usefull to know what u put into the include.

echo the result of get_404_template(); (before the big if statement )

echo some text before the $template = get_index_template();

this will give u some information on where it goes wrong. I think its a problem in the settings or template but thats always hard to find.

edit 2: 
i wonder where the 'none' comes from. it comes from one of those get_ fucntions. but u have to find out witch one. If u know it it also might help in the search on where the 'none' comes from. It lookd like a setting.

Comment: But the theme is having the template for 404 and it's located in the theme folder

Comment: Iam no wp expert. :P i have no experience with creating WP themes. sorry

Comment: open the template-loader.php, add a echo $template before the include on line 75.

Comment: That's fine Sliver, let some other guy help out. Anyways thanks for pointing.

Comment: typed out a edit. It might help. You can just fidel with wp source and find the problem. by debugging the hole wp system.

Comment: And how do I debug?

Comment: just echo the values and check if they are correct. debug is finding the problem. i usaly check if values are filled correctly.